# Hover não funciona em div

Tags: jquery, css

Tenho o seguinte código HTML:

```
<li style="background-image: url(fotoSYS)" class="produtos f-left margin-right-30 margin-top-30">
  <div style="background-color:codigoSYS"class="marcador"></div>
  <h2>tituloSYS</h2>
</li>
```

O CSS está assim:

```
.produtos{
    width: 294px;
    height: 349px;
    background-color: #f1f2f2;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .4s ease-out;
}
.produtosHover{
    border-color: #dddb00;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px gray;
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: none;
}
```

O Jquery está assim:

```
$(".produtos").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).children(".produtosHover").show();
  },
  function() {
    $(this).children(".produtosHover").hide();
  }
);
```

Eu quero, que quando eu passe o mouse em cima de `produtos`, ele aplique o `produtosHover`, que irá apenas colocar uma borda, um box e um margin-top, usei o `children` pois terá mais de um elemento. 
Eu vou fazer via Jquery, pois o `border-color` será gerenciável pelo cliente.

Porém, não sei o que está errado =/

Comment: Onde está o elemento com classe .produtosHover no seu código HTML?

Comment: Felipe, pode corrigir o HTML para a pergunta ficar mais clara? não vejo nehuma classe `.produtosHover`

Answer (score 6):

Você não precisa de jQuery para isso, CSS basta.

Mude

```
.produtosHover{
    border-color: #dddb00;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px gray;
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: none;
}
```

para

```
.produtos:hover {
    border-color: #dddb00;
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px gray;
    margin-top: 15px;
/*  display: none; # isto não precisa  */
}
```

#### Exemplo: http://jsfiddle.net/gcf82uLu/

Comment: Prefiro fazer desse modo, sem o `jQuery`, apenas com `CSS`!

Comment: Eu havia feito dessa forma, tranquilo. O que acontece, é que essa cor da borda, o border-color, será gerenciável pelo cliente, esqueci de comentar isso no post.

Comment: @FelipeStoker, nesse caso nem com o addClass a coisa lá vai. Como é que o cliente escolhe a cor?

Comment: Existe uma palavra reservada chamada `codigoSYS`, que no no gerenciador será o campo "COR", e lá o cliente irá colocar a cor em hexadecimal. Acho que vou ter que fazer isso inline mesmo.

Comment: De fato, para mudar a cor, vai precisar de um JS mais especializado, ou gerar o CSS dinamicamente, que daria problemas com cache. Melhor por um style inline pra cor, e deixar só os outros detalhes na classe.

Comment: Então, acho que vou deixar o inline `style="border-color:#dddb00"` e as outras definições, e adicionar uma classe. Quando passa o mouse em cima, vou tentar um `css` via `jquery`

Comment: @FelipeStoker há algum refresh da página entre o cliente inserir a cor e o hover? senão podia fazer esse estilo logo no lado do servidor

Comment: Não. O cliente vai cadastrar um produto pelo gerenciador. E nesse gerenciador, além dos campos imagens e descrição, há o campo `cor`, que é o `codigoSYS` que está no meu PHP. Ele insere e estará lá sempre, sem refresh.

Comment: @FelipeStoker podia ter um `<style>` na página que muda o conteudo com jQuery/regex quando a cor é inserida. Assim mudaria diretamente no css do hover. Mas talvez seja mais prático fazer isso inline.

Comment: será que funciona com atributos?

Comment: @FelipeStoker style inline é melhor

Comment: E como eu poderia fazer isso, com o código que já possuo?

Comment: @FelipeStoker coloque o html desse input para a cor

Comment: Input? como assim?

Comment: @FelipeStoker, eu queria dizer código relecionado com `"e lá o cliente irá colocar a cor em hexadecimal"`. Para poder dar um exemplo.

Comment: Entendi.
O HTML ficará assim: `<div style="border-color:codigoSYS"class="marcador"></div>`, ou seja, o `border-color` inline, tem o `codigoSYS` que recebe o valor em hexadecimal que o cliente irá informar no gerenciador.

Comment: Hmmm, e o código que troca esse `codigoSYS` pelo decimal`? o cliente escreve à mão ou escolhe numa combo/select?

Answer (score 5):

Se eu entendi direito, você quer aplicar a classe `.produtosHover` em `.produtos`?

Se for isto, deve usar `addClass` e `removeClass`, pois `show` e `hide` trabalham sobre elementos já existentes apenas.

Solução:

```
$(".produtos").hover(
  function() {
    $(this).addClass("produtosHover");
  },
  function() {
    $(this).removeClass("produtosHover");
  }
);
```

> Não se esqueça de tirar o `display: none` do .produtosHover para fazer o teste.

Comment: Olhe também a solução do @Sergio, pois se não precisar de compatibilidade com IE mais velho (que só aceita :hover em ancora), a dele é mais simples que o JQuery.

Answer (score 2):

Primeiro tens um erro na classe `produtosHover` do css. Tens de remover o `display: none;`.

Em segundo, basta adicionares da seguinte maneira as classes css:

```
$(".produtos").hover(
  function() {
    //$(this).children(".produtosHover").show();
    $(this).addClass("produtosHover");
  },
  function() {
    //$(this).children(".produtosHover").hide();
    $(this).removeClass("produtosHover");
  }
);
```

Deixo aqui exemplo online: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/fvwtgbug/)

Comment: @Bacco ja respondeu da mesma maneira que a sua, está identico!

Comment: Sim, mas antes de ele editar a pergunta tinha `$(this).addClass("produtosHover").show()` e `$(this).removeClass("produtosHover").hide();`, o que está errado... Na resposta dele ainda não fazia referência ao `display: none;` antes da edição, o que torna a minha válida e correta :)

Comment: Correto! Não tinha visto. @CesarMiguel (:

Comment: Certo @Exception ;)

Comment: O `none` eu de fato pus depois, mas o show e o hide eu corrigi imediatamente depois da postagem, e bem antes desta resposta (não que isso faça nenhuma diferença agora).

Answer (score 0):

Basta incluir um pequeno bloco `<style>` no HTML contendo a propriedade editável, e o restante no CSS, assim:

**HTML:**

```
<style>.produtos:hover { border-color: codigoSYS }</style>
<li style="background-image: url(fotoSYS)" class="produtos f-left margin-right-30 margin-top-30">
    <div style="background-color:codigoSYS" class="marcador"></div>
     <h2>tituloSYS</h2>
</li>
```

**CSS:**

```
.produtos {
    width: 294px;
    height: 349px;
    background-color: #f1f2f2;
    border: 3px solid transparent;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: all .4s ease-out;
}
.produtos:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 0 25px gray;
    margin-top: 15px;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jaderw/tmb8bafx/)